# Painfully slow ajax calls using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm using knockout in my application to register/login from a form but the wait times on ajax calls are painfully slow first time 'round (guessing it's caching afterwards as it's really quick second time 'round) - around fifteen seconds to login when I upload the site online, and when I wrap it up as an iOS app (HTML5 application) it takes over SIXTY seconds to complete login. Why could this be happening? Have I missed something? Is it more likely to be server-side? Hopefully I can give enough info but unfortunately I'm new to this. I'll add the Login code below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    function UserViewModel() {

        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;

       var Domain = "http://example.com";

        //Declare User observables which will be bind with UI
        self.UserId = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.Email = ko.observable();
        self.Occupation = ko.observable();
        self.Country = ko.observable();
        self.RegistrationNumber = ko.observable();

        //Create User object
        var User = {
            UserId: self.UserId,
            Name: self.Name,
            Email: self.Email,
            Occupation: self.Occupation,
            Country: self.Country,
            RegistrationNumber: self.RegistrationNumber,
        };

        //Assign knockout observables to User/s objects
        self.User = ko.observable();  //user
        self.Users = ko.observableArray(); // list of users

        //onload set status of user
        UserStatus();

        //Login handler
        self.login = function () {

            try {

                if (User.Email() != "" && User.RegistrationNumber() != "") {

                    //try logging in
                    Login();

                } else {
                    viewModel.UserId("Please login with the correct email and registration number.");
                }
            }

            catch (err) {
                viewModel.UserId("There was an error, please try again.");
            }

        };

    //Login
        function Login() {


            $.ajax({
                   url: Domain + '/User/Login',
                   cache: false,
                   type: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   data: '{"Email":"' + User.Email() + '","RegistrationNumber":"' + User.RegistrationNumber() + '"}',
                   beforeSend: function () {
                       // setting a timeout
                     $('.splash').show();

                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                   $('.splash').hide();
                   if (data != 0) {

                   SetUserVars(data.UserId, data.Name, data.Email, data.Occupation, data.Country, data.RegistrationNumber);

                   viewModel.UserId(ActionToTake());
                   }
                   else {
                   viewModel.UserId("The supplied credentials are invalid, please try again.");
                   }
                   },
                   complete: function () {
                    //$('.splash').hide(); 
                   },
                   }).fail(
                           function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                           console.log(xhr.statusText);
                           console.log(textStatus);
                           console.log(err);
                           viewModel.UserId("There was an error, please try again.");
                           });
        }

function UserStatus() {

        if (localStorage.getItem("UserId") === null) {

            //not logged in
            $("a.menu-status").text("Login").attr("href", "index.html#login-screen");

        }
        if (localStorage.getItem("UserId") != null) {
            //logged in
            $("a.menu-status").text("Logout").attr("href", "index.html#login-screen");



        }

        //allow user to logout and reset all user storage
        $("a.menu-status").click(function () {

            //show logged off status
            $("a.menu-status").text("Login");

            alert('You have logged off, please login if you wish to continue.');

            self.reset();

            //redirect

            window.location.replace("index.html#login-screen");
            location.reload();
            viewModel.UserId("You have logged off.");

            ResetUserLocalStorage();

        });

    }
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with your client side code.  You can use the debugger or an listener like Fiddler to monitor the network traffic and see where it is getting hung up at

Comment: @QBM5 The traffic is getting hung up at the Login xhr request - it says the size is 580b and the time was 9.88 seconds.

Comment: Do you have access to the server.  It sounds like the server is lagging, not the client

Comment: @QBM5 Yes, I do - can you suggest a course of action to take to check that please?

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont know how helpful I will be on that.  I do not know what kind of server you are running.  Dont know what mechanisms you use for the login.  If you are able to I would suggest walking through the server side code step by step to see what function is taking its time in returning.  And then debug that function.  I dont have enough information to help beyond that

Comment: @QBM5 Thank you. It's just confusing to me that it's super quick after the first call. When I wrap it up in Xcode and test it on an iPad it's horrendously slow. I'll check the server-side code.

Comment: Hahaha, I am not an xcode fan.  So I will leave it at that :)

Comment: You should change the subject of the question, you're using jQuery for ajax, it has nothing to do with Knockout.

Comment: @SteenTøttrup cheers - will do.

Comment: Try removing `contentType` from your ajax request. Dunno why, but for me it made a big speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Id be inclined to agree with the comments that the issue lies with the server side and not the client side.

The steps id take initially would be to use something like postman https://www.getpostman.com/ and hit the API through that, verify that its the slow part.

If that shows the issue then can you get yourself in a debug situation with the code thats running on the server? Then step through the code and try to pin point exactly whats happening and where its slowing down.